# MongoID Helper Method for Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

Hey how can i create a method in my MongoID model that will return the username field value of the name field isn't set.

So if I have a user...and the user.name is Thomas then when calling user.name you will get Thomas. If user.name isn't set and you call user.name then it will return the username for the user while still calling user.name. I want to do this as a fail safe. Is it possible?

Comment: I have no idea what the question is about here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you could just override the `name` accessor with something like this:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :username, :type => String
  field :name,     :type => String

  def name
    # You can access the fields by name using `model[field_name]`
    # or `model.attributes[field_name]`
    self['name'] || self['username']
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you could use a lambda as `:name`'s default:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :username, :type => String
  field :name,     :type => String, :default => lambda { self.username }
end
```

In either case, saying `u.name` would give you the `:name` field if it is set and `:username` otherwise.

If "isn't set" could mean that `user.name == ''` rather than `user.name.nil?` then you could modify the first approach thusly:

```
def name
  self['name'].present?? self['name'] : self['username']
end
```

Comment: You are correct about what i want but for some reason the above code isn't working i'm just returned nothing if the name isn't set.

Comment: Well, both of those work for me and there's nothing terribly tricky involved. So what does your `User` class look like and what exactly do your attempts look like?

Comment: You can't use the `||` operator since an empty string is a truthy value. You need to use `blank?`

Comment: @Pierre-LouisGottfrois: If there's an empty string rather than `nil`. It is difficult to know what's really going on here but that could be it.